# How to use an API with an app Fiori (SAPUI5)

Tags: javascript, ajax, sapui5

I am trying to use this [Mercedes Benz API](https://developer.mercedes-benz.com/apis/image_api/docs) in my app. Inside controller I have a ajax request:

```
    onInit : function () {
        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        var url = 'https://api.mercedes-benz.com/image/v1/vehicles/WDDZH3HB8JA394212/components?apikey=my_apikey';

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                //armamos la url y la asignamos a una var       
            },
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            accepts: "application/json",
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, estado, error) {
                console.log(error +":" + " " + estado)
            },
            timeout: 10000
        });
    },
```

I just want response as `OK` but getting some error:

> Request header field X-XHR-Logon is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**Responses**
[image: response]

[image: response]

If you take a look to the documentation API I just need the API key. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Guide me if you has use an API inside a FIORI app it will be thankful

NOTE: my fiori server is on premise so we don't use SCP

Comment: if you put a debugger statement in the `beforeSend` event, can you see `x-xhr-logon` in the headers of the request?

Comment: you know of destinations in SAP cloud platform? 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e4f1d97cbb571014a247d10f9f9a685d.html

You can fix this issue by having a destination created to the URL you are trying to call

Comment: my fiori server is on premise so we don't use SCP :C

Comment: @Jorg i put a break but where can i see that ? this is my first time that i use ajax :C maybe there is another way

Comment: replace `//armamos la url y la asignamos a una var ` with `debugger;`, and add an import parameter to the function: `beforeSend: function(request)`. Then open the console of the browser. Chrome will stop and you can check the values of `request`, in a similar way to SE80. Check the Sources tab.

Comment: wich of the properties: overrideMimeType
pipe
progress
promise
readyState
setRequestHeader
state
statusC
success
then

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do an XHR you need to whitelist APIKEY in neo-app.json like this

```
{
    "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
    "routes": [{
        ...
    ],
    "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true,
    "headerWhiteList": [
        "APIKey"
    ]
}
```

Otherwise I strictly recommend using destinations, explained in here:

- [SAPUI5 / AJAX, submitting Basic Authentication Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167302/sapui5-ajax-submitting-basic-authentication-details) (solved)
- [Authentication API in SAPUI5 without SAP Cloud Platform and Destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422857/authentication-api-in-sapui5-without-sap-cloud-platform-and-destinations) (not solved)

Comment: that's my case, without SCP my fiori server is on premise

Comment: I doubt that anyone might solve this satisfying to anyone not revoking security patterns. Maybe you should build an OData Service in SAP onPrem, calling your external API and provide this to your app. I dont see any other solutions here. And yes you could also do HTTP requests from abap ... thats revoking security because your onPrem has to communicate with the internet...

Comment: maybe using a proxy on the fiori server ? and i never has build an odata that communicates with internet :O i din't know that

Comment: it is ABAP doing an http request, you could put it in an odata service and work with the response in your app. https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/09/calling-an-external-restful-service-from-abap-http-method-post/

Comment: thanks! but i think i have to make a https request or i will get an error in abap is it possible to ?